# How to copy and paste indd file content into an another indd file?

Tags: adobe, copy-paste, extendscript, adobe-indesign

I'm newbie in indesign scripting stuffs.So I apologise as I couldn't post my trials.

**Objective:**
I have an indd document which will have figure caption,label etc. I need to copy content(figure which is editable) from other indd file to this document where related figure label exists.

**For example:**
sample.indd

```
Some text   
Fig.1.1 caption
some text
```

I need to copy the content of figure1.indd and paste into the sample.indd document where `Fig.1.1` string exists and so on. Now I'm doing it manually. But am supposed to automate this.

So, I need some hint how to acheive it using extendscript?

I have found something like below to do this, but I don't have any clue to develop it further and also am not sure whether this approach is correct to get my result. Pls help me

```
myDocument=app.open(File("file.indd"),false);  //opening a file to get the content without showing.
myDocument.pages.item(0).textFrames.item(0).contents="some text"; 
//here I could set the content but I don't knw how to get the content

// ?????? Then I have to paste the content into active document.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the script for my requirement.

```
var myDoc = File("sample.indd");//Destination File  
var myFigDoc = File("fig.indd");//Figure File  
app.open(File(myFigDoc));  
app.activeDocument.pageItems.everyItem().select();  
app.copy();  
app.open(File(myDoc));  
app.findGrepPreferences = app.changeGrepPreferences = null;  
app.findGrepPreferences.findWhat = "FIG. 1.1 ";//Figure caption text  
//app.findGrepPreferences.appliedParagraphStyle = "FigureCaption";//Figure Caption Style  
myFinds = app.activeDocument.findGrep();  
for(var i=0;i<myFinds.length;i++){  
    myFinds[i].insertionPoints[0].contents="\r";  
    myFinds[i].insertionPoints[0].select();  
    app.paste();  
}  
app.findGrepPreferences = app.changeGrepPreferences = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

If acceptable for you, you can place an indesign file as link (place…). So a script could try to catch the "fig…" strings and do the importation.
Have a look at scripts that use finGrep() and place() command.

Comment: If I place a link of file into the document,how will i get my output?  Manually am doing like, open a indd file.select all , copy and paste it into the target indd file.

Comment: i need to copy the content of a file rather than a file

Comment: If I do like this,  `myTextFrame.place(File("fig.indd"));` it places like an figure (non editable without frames). If i select all and do copy and paste only then it places as editable fig in the target.

Comment: I understand. You could as well use app.select()/copy()/paste()…